# RESTful web services vs Socket Programming for a Data Intensive Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, networking, rest, architecture

I'm building a web application with Ruby on Rails which needs to be highly scalable.  In this application, data is produced by a mobile client (approximately 20 bytes) every second.  All of this data must be transferred to a server at some point, preferably as soon as possible.

To accomplish this task, I want the server to act as a RESTful service.  The client could buffer locations (say every 5 to 30 seconds) and then shoot them off as a HTTP put request, where the server could then store them.  I believe this model is simpler to implement, and better handles high volume traffic, as the clients could keep buffering data until they hear a response from the server.

My boss, on the other hand, wants to implement the server using socket programming.  He believes socket programming will result in less data being transferred, which will increase the total efficiency of the system.  I can't disagree on this point, but I think given modern bandwidth the extra overhead with HTTP is worth it.  Plus, I think trying to maintain thousands (or millions) of simultaneous connects with users will cause its own problems and greatly increase the complexity of the server.

Honestly, I don't know the right approach to this problem, so I thought I'd post it here and get the opinions of much smarter people than myself.  I'd appreciate it if any answers included the pros and cons of the proposed solution.

Thanks.

**Update**

We now have a few additional requirements flushed out.  First, the mobile client cannot upload more than 5 GB of data per month.  In this case, we're talking one message a second for eight hours a day per month.  Second is we want's to combine messages as little as possible.  This is to ensure if something happens to the mobile client (say a car crash), we lose as little data as possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your boss appears to be optimizing prematurely, which is not really a good idea.

Instead of trying to fight an imaginary performance bogeyman before you've even started writing your code, you should examine your application's requirements and design to them. Don't let perceived problems drive your design.

If it comes to it, have your boss outline exactly how he'd marshal data across his socket connection and then do some quick calculations to see if you could match or beat them with HTTP. Will he use something like Google's Protocol Buffers, or write his own marshaling protocol? If so, will it be self-describing? How about application "verbs" like what you'd get for free in HTTP? Will his connections be persistent? There's a lot more to "sockets" than just opening a connection and spewing bytes down it.

You've also correctly noted that your boss seems to be favoring raw speed of sockets over everything else: scalability, maintainability, availability of development and testing tools, protocol sniffers, the helpful semantics of the HTTPS verbs, and so on. HTTP is well understood by load balancers and firewalls and the like. Your proprietary socket protocol will not be so lucky.

What I'd suggest is you look into all the options out there and evaluate them from a performance perspective through testing, prototyping and benchmarking. Then weigh those numbers against the difficulty of building and maintaining the application with that technology.

Comment: Thank you for the well though out and detailed answer.  I never really considered HTTP could beat out socket programming in terms of performance.  Considering a HTTP post request would take 1.5 to 2 KB of data, is that possible?

Comment: Why would a HTTP post take 1,5 to 2kb data? You can post anything (like JSON or zipped XML)

Comment: I pulled that information from here: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html.  Did I misinterpret it?

Comment: I think your idea in your original question to batch the data (and only transmit every 5-30 seconds) would easily spread out the "cost" of using HTTP to the point that it would become negligible.

Comment: I've posted a couple additional requirements for this project.  Does your answer still remain the same in light of them?

Comment: You need to define your requirement to lose "as little data as possible". Are you building a kind of flight data recorder for mobile devices that is going to track the device's location? If so, even an update every (say) 10 seconds would still put the last known position very close to the actual. Anyway, even sending about 1Kb/sec leads you to about 900Mb per month given 8 hours/day activity. BTW, you do realize that constantly sending data from a mobile device will absolutely kill its battery, right? That's why techniques like long-lived sync calls (ala Direct Push) are heavily used there.

Comment: Oh, and yes, HTTP would still be my choice.

Comment: The location tracking is part of the requirements of this project, but it's important that the data not be lost in transmission.  And we've anticipated the battery issue, and it shouldn't be a problem as most clients are expected to use portable chargers for the mobile devices.

Comment: You will have to have some amount of tolerance for data loss if/when the device fails or is destroyed, regardless of your choice of protocol. There's just no way around that, so if your boss is saying that "no data can ever be lost", you should point out that it's impossible to guarantee it. The race condition will always exist that something could happen between transmissions.

Answer (score 9):

Stick to HTTP.

It's far easier to create a park of HTTP servers and put them behind a load balancer than to try do the same thing with for your own protocol. Why? Everything already exists for HTTP.

### Update

What you need to reimplement yourself:

- Buffer management (important if your load is high)
- Making sure that you've received an entire message (A simple `Receive`/`BeginReceive` is not enough)
- Asynchronous socket handling
- Authentication
- A load balancer (this part is tricky and you need to design it carefully)
- Your own protocol (you need a way to identify when you've received an entire message)

If you use ASP.NET MVC + JSON (the steps for merb or rails is similar):

1. Create a new website
2. Activate digest authentication in IIS
3. Create a new controller, tag it with the `[Authorize]` attribute
4. Add an action

What is cheapest? A server or having you spend a month on something that already have been done?

Comment: Forgive me for the naive question, but what will I be missing?

Comment: Sorry.  You said everything already exists for HTTP.  What all will I have to recode with socket programming?

Comment: Hi, I added a couple additional requirements.  Could you please tell me if your answer remains the same?

Comment: yes it do. Android got sqlite built in, and any application can use it. a) Store all info in it. b) have a separate thread which uploads the info. Conclusion: No info is lost and HTTP can still be used, and you consume less bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

Your boss and you are both right, and the correct choice depends on business requirements: how soon you're going to have to scale.

If you're a start up launching a new service and you're afraid you won't be able to manage the millions of new users you're going to have within 3 months, then @Brian-Kelly is right - this is premature optimization. OTOH, if you're Twitter and you're building a new location-based service, then scale is the primary issue you should deal with. If you're somewhere in between then, well, it's your business - make the choice.

Building a RESTful web service with Rails is quick and simple and calling it from the mobile client is simple as well (though buffering on the mobile client end does require more code). This is a the main (and only imho) advantage of this approach in your case - and it's a huge advantage.

However, HTTP does add a lot of overhead. If your messages are 20 byte long, there's in fact **several times more overhead than payload** per message. That means more network bandwidth and more CPU time. Yes, you can add more servers to handle it, but it'll cost you - requiring several servers to do work achievable by one.

If your service is just receiving very short messages from mobile clients, and *if it's OK* for it to lose the occasional message, then I'd consider using UDP. Your 20 bytes should fit inside a single packet. That saves a lot compared with TCP's several round trips to first establish a connection, then send the data.

Another thing to keep in mind when you consider whether optimization is premature in your case is the mobile clients: it's simple to make changes to your server, but pushing a new version that uses a more optimized messaging protocol to millions of devices 'out in the field' is not trivial.

**Update**, following the update to the question:

5 GB per month is plenty. A message every second for a month means 86,400*30 =~ 2.6M messages.
That allows you to spend almost 2K per message. Not a problem if your payload is ~ 20 bytes...

As for your preference not to combine messages so as not to lose any information, you'll have to ask yourself how many messages are OK to lose. Maybe a whole minute is too much, but 10 seconds isn't a problem? a client moving at 60mph would only move 0.16 miles in 10 seconds.

In any case, if this is a real-time system that's supposed to save lives, consider doing some testing in real-life conditions (mobile client on the road). That's the only way to determine how the mobile network(s) behaves - what latencies you can expect, how often packets are lost, arrive out of sequence etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've posted a couple of additional requirements for the project.  I'd appreciate it if you could comment on them as well.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP was designed to scale based on the assumption that the vast majority of requests are GETs.  It sounds like the most of your interactions are the client sending data to the server.   I think it is quite probable that there exists a better architectural style than REST to achieve what you are trying to do.

The question is, can you afford the time to start from scratch, or is HTTP good enough for your needs. Without knowing more details about your app, I think it is difficult to give good advice.

Comment: That's a good point. A big advantage of REST is that GETs get cached but that's completely irrelevant for helixed's problem.